# How do I get the current font size of selected text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, font-size, selected

I am using contentededitable on a div and want to add an increase font size button for selected text.

Selected text meaning highlighted with the cursor.

In order to run 
    `document.execCommand('fontsize', false, size);`
I need to know the size of the selected text, so I can increase it by 1. How do I get the font size of the currently selected text?

I tried:
    `var size = document.getSelection().fontSize.toString();`
but that was no bueno. I also tried 
    `document.execCommand('increaseFontSize', true, 1)`
assuming it would increase it by one integer, but nothing happens, not even an error.

I tried this:

`var el = document.getSelection();`

`var size = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');`

But I get the error 
`Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can determine the `font-size` of the parent element like this:

```
const selection = Window.getSelection();
if (selection) { // make sure it doesn't error if nothing is selected
  const size = window.getComputedStyle(selection.anchorNode.parentElement, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
}
```

`Window.getSelection()` returns a [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object. On those objects, the property [`anchorNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/anchorNode) contains a reference to the `textNode` that selection is part of. That, in turn, has the usual `parentElement` property. From there it's easy.

Comment: But what is el? When using getSelection() there doesn't seem to be an element referenced.

Comment: I've renamed it to make it more clear. It's a `Selection` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Comment: Got it, var el = document.getSelection();